# Open generic type inheritance dynamic identification in C#

Tags: c#, generics

When I have two non-generic `Type` objects `a` and `b`, I can easily verify whether a is assignable from b by using the `a.IsAssignableFrom(b)` function.

```
class ClassBase { }
class ClassDerived : ClassBase { }
...
typeof(ClassBase).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(ClassDerived)) //returns true
```

Now say I have two generic interfaces:

```
interface IBase<T> { }
interface IDerived<T> : IBase<T> { }
```

If I close them down, I can do the same thing as before, with exactly the same behaviour, e.g.

```
typeof(IBase<object>).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IDerived<object>)) //returns true
```

In fact, any `T` that can be used to close down `IDerived` can also be used to close down `IBase` and `IBase<T>` is assignable from `IDerived<T>` (for that particular T).

However,

```
typeof(IBase<>).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IDerived<>)) //returns false
```

I sort of have an idea why that might be so (they can be closed down on different types and thus get inconvertible?). I understand that a function that does return true in this case is thus somewhat different. The question is: "Is `IBase<T>` assignable from `IDerived<T>` for every valid `T`?" (thanks to [hvd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/743382/hvd))

**What I thought of doing** is closing the generics and then asking whether they are assignable. But to be general, I would need to close down under the most generic type(s) `b` can take and that could be a) ugly, b) quite hard to do.

Another approach is to go up the implementation/inheritance tree on `b` and try comparing it to `a`.

My **question** is whether there is an easier way of doing this even in general cases.

**Motivation:** general interest, as I don't actually need this at the end. However, the initial need for this came while I was using Ninject with open and closed generics and I needed to resolve whether an open generic class can be cast to an open generic interface (class).

Comment: I'm not sure it even makes sense to ask that *question* for two **open** generic types such as `IBase<>`.

Comment: "Another approach is to go up the implementation/inheritance tree on b and try comparing it to a." -- that's what I would do, if I really needed this.

Comment: @MarcGravell "Is `IBase<T>` assignable from `IDerived<T>` for every valid `T`" is a sensible question, and I think that's the question that's asked.

Comment: @hvd yes, but that is **not** the same as asking about `IBase<>` and `IDerived<>`; there is not implicit "for the same T" there.

Comment: @MarcGravell Indeed, but the OP realises that, see "(they can be closed down on different types and thus get inconvertible?)" from the question.

Comment: @hvd yes, but that doesn't change anything. Simply; as far as reflection is concerned, there *is no implicit* "for the same T". So if you are trying to test that, you will need to write it manually.

Comment: I have added _for that particular T_ to hopefully make it a bit clearer and also the somewhat better formulation of my question from hvd - thank you for that.

@MarcGravell I am well aware of the differences and I know that they can get inconvertible. Also, I understand that there is no implicit "for the same T" in there, that's why I added it explicitly, although I see that I haven't made myself completely clear.

The question mark in why the `IsAssignableFrom` function doesn't do what I want is there because I am not sure whether there are more fundamental reasons for that.

Comment: @MarcGravell put it like this: when we write `IDerived<T> : Base<T> { }` we are expressing a certain fact about these two interfaces. What this fact is is obvious to human eyes; but how can we determine *at runtime* if this fact is true, given the open types? What does 'writing it manually' look like?

Comment: Surely, declaring `IDerived<T>` with constraints that contradict those of `Base<T>` would be compile-time invalid, so the question is *always* true for any valid `T`?

Comment: And regarding the specific AssignableFrom call you mention: only the "closed" form of the generic is a true runtime type (you can't create a variable of type `IBase<>`), and so `AssignableFrom` without closing the generic first would appear to have no useful meaning.

Comment: @DanPuzey: As mentioned above by AakashM, the useful meaning would be whether one of the types is assignable to another given that both have received the same generic argument. As pointed out by the OP, the question could in theory be solved by calling `MakeGenericType` on both open generic types and specifying an arbitrary `T`, but finding an arbitrary `T` that conforms to all the generic constraints of `IDerived<T>` may be non-trivial.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper thanks for clarifying. Seems to be an interesting theoretical question, though I fail to see a practical application. I wonder if this is something that can be answered in IL and simply isn't available through C#/CLR methods?

Comment: @DanPuzey: I'm not sure about the practical application for this particular question, but I've recently had a lot of similar *fun* with generic types and reflection when I created something like a bijective map of data classes vs. visualization classes, both of which were registered as open generic types because some of the generic parameters would only be known at runtime and there should be only one instance of the map, regardless of some of the generic arguments.

Answer (score 1):

The example you provided of an generic interface inheriting directly from another generic masks the complexity in resolving compatibility between open generics. For more on that, read Eric Lippert's recent blog entry: [Why not automatically infer constraints?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2012/03/09/why-not-automatically-infer-constraints.aspx).

Deferring to Eric's notes in the linked article, I will not attempt to solve the general case of determining if generic interfaces are assignable from each other in all cases. A substantial part of that solution would require determining if the constraints (if any) on the two types intersect at all. You would also have to decide what you *want* your hypothetical method to return when one open generic interface is assignable to the other in some cases but not others, which would happen if there are overlapping but not coincident constraints.

**Updated**

For comparing direct inheritance "walking up the tree" as you suggest is pretty easy if you package it in an extension method. However, for actually determining whether two open generic types are equal you will have to define your own comparison, as the built in equality comparison doesn't work on the type definitions retrieved by `GetInterfaces` or `BaseType` called on a generic type:

```
typeof(Base<>) == typeof(Derived<>).BaseType; // Returns false
typeof(IBase<>) == typeof(Base<>).GetInterfaces()[0]; // Returns false
```

This probably derives from the fact that open generic types retrieved from `BaseType` or `GetInterfaces()` have null `FullName` properties, even though the `Namespace` and `Name` properties are populated. I therefoe defined by own `GetFullName()` extension method as well, with an optional `strongName` parameter to determin whether to include the full assembly name.

So, here is fairly compact implementation for comparing direct ineheritance or implementation between open generic types:

```
public static class TypeExtensions {
    public static bool OpenIsAssignableFrom(this Type baseType, Type c, bool strongName = true) {
        if (!baseType.IsGenericTypeDefinition || !c.IsGenericTypeDefinition) return false;
        if (baseType.IsInterface)
            return c.ImplementsOpenInterface(baseType);
        Type testBaseType = c;
        while (testBaseType != null) {
            if (baseType.GetFullName(strongName) == testBaseType.GetFullName(strongName)) return true;
            testBaseType = testBaseType.BaseType;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static bool ImplementsOpenInterface(this Type sourceType, Type ifaceType, bool strongName = true) {
        if (!ifaceType.IsInterface) return false;
        return sourceType.GetInterfaces().Any(I => I.GetFullName(strongName) == ifaceType.GetFullName(strongName));
    }

    public static string GetFullName(this Type type, bool strongName = false) {
        string name = type.FullName ?? "";
        if (name.Length == 0)
            name = type.Namespace + "." + type.Name;
        if (strongName)
            name += ", " + type.Assembly.FullName;
        return name;
    }
}
```

Given the following open generic interfaces:

```
namespace TypeExample {
    public interface IBase<T> { }
    public interface IDerived<T> : IBase<T> { }
    public interface IDerived2<T> : IDerived<T> { }

    public class Base<T> : IBase<T> { }
    public class Derived<T> : Base<T>, IDerived<T> { }
    public class Derived2<T> : Derived<T>, IDerived2<T> { }
}
```

All of the following will return `true`:

```
typeof(IBase<>).OpenIsAssignableFrom(typeof(Base<>));
typeof(IBase<>).OpenIsAssignableFrom(typeof(Derived2<>));
typeof(Base<>).OpenIsAssignableFrom(typeof(Derived2<>));
typeof(IBase<>).OpenIsAssignableFrom(typeof(IDerived2<>));
```

Which is the inituitive identical result as the following using constructed generic types and the built in IsAssignableFrom:

```
typeof(IBase<string>).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(Base<string>));
typeof(IBase<string>).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(Derived2<string>));
typeof(Base<string>).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(Derived2<string>));
typeof(IBase<string>).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IDerived2<string>));
```

Comment: Now let's add to the complexity... What does your `OpenIsAssignableFrom` return for `typeof(IBase<,>).OpenIsAssignableFrom(typeof(IDerived<,>))`, where `IDerived<T,U>` implements `IBase<U,T>` instead of `IBase<T,U>`? What should it return? (I don't have an answer for that last question either.)

Comment: @hvd It would return true, as it does not take any constraints into account. After all, `IBase<U, T>` _can_ be assignable from  `IDerived<T, U>` when `T` and `U` are the same type.

Answer (score 1):

As you've already found out, `typeof(IBase<>).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IDerived<>))` will never return true, since the two open generic types aren't in each others inheritance hierarchies.

> My question is whether there is an easier way of doing this even in general cases.

No, not *easier*, but...

If `T` doesn't have any constraints (`where T: ...`) for either of the two generic types you're checking assignability for I think you might be able to construct the closed generic types by using `object` as type parameter, and then using `IsAssignableFrom` on the constructed types.

If `T` is constrained on any of the generic types, you will have to use reflection to find those constraints ([Type.GetGenericArguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenericarguments.aspx), [Type.GetGenericParameterConstraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenericparameterconstraints.aspx)), and then construct the generic types using that information. In this scenario, the constraining types must still be the same because of the `A<T> : B<T>` inheritance (the same `T`) in order to have the possibility of assignability between the two generic types. Note that if one constraining type is inheriting the other, you will find assignability of the generic types if you construct them both with the most derived of the two constraining types.

Here are some examples:

```
    public class A<T> {}
    public class B<T> : A<T> {}

    public class C<T> where T: E {}
    public class D<T> : C<T> where T: F {}

    public class E {}
    public class F : E {}
    public class G : F {}

    typeof(A<>).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(B<>))              // false
    typeof(A<object>).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(B<object>))  // true
    typeof(A<string>).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(B<string>))  // true
    typeof(C<E>).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(D<F>))            // false
    typeof(C<F>).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(D<F>))            // true
    typeof(C<G>).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(D<G>))            // true
```

Comment: I think it's sufficient to look at the constraints of the most specialized type, isn't it? Surely, the more generalized type cannot be more constrained if it receives its actual generic argument from the specialized type in the inheritance chain.

Comment: Yes, if the two generic types are related. If they are, it would be a compile time error for the more specialized type to have a less specialized constraint.

Comment: Ah, you're correct. Somehow, I was assuming that it's at least known which one of the types is *suspected* to be assignable to which one, but of course that's not guaranteed.

Comment: Well, you're correct too. And you made me think - that's a good thing! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

An old question but since I came across it in a search and came up with (IMHO) a better answer I'll just leave this here...

The `BaseType` property on an open generic type returned from `GetGenericTypeDefinition` will not be comparable for the reasons noted by Joshua.

However, the `BaseType` property of the closed generic type will return a closed generic type of the base. So you can walk up the tree of closed generics, until one has matching open `GetGenericTypeDefinition`.

```
bool InheritsOpenGeneric(Type type, Type openGenericType)
{
   if (!type.IsGenericType) return false;
   if (type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == openGenericType) return true;
   return InheritsOpenGeneric(type.BaseType, openGenericType);
}
```